# xcode request data from php/mysql using NSURLConnection

Tags: php, mysql, xcode, nsurlconnection

I would like to use NSURLConnection to get a value (can be 1 or 0) from a PHP/Mysql request, below is my xcode and code for php/mysql query

can anyone help me please store the received data in a NSString instead of NSMutableData?
The reason why I would like to use NSURLConnection is because it offers the no connection function

```
NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.20/iqkradio_stream_ip_flag.php"]
                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                      timeoutInterval:20.0];
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
if (theConnection) {
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    NSString *receivedDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

else
{
    NSLog(@"no connection or Error");
    // Inform the user that the connection failed.
}
```

Mysql file

```
 <?php
$con = mysql_connect("192.168.0.15","xxxx","xxxxx");

if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("qkradio", $con);
$result = mysql_query("select address from iqkradio" );
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['address'];
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a single character why not just use:

```
NSError *error;
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.20/iqkradio_stream_ip_flag.php"] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
```

It's much easier than `NSURLConnection` and shouldn't block much with such a small payload.  If you're worried about that you can always wrap it in an `dispatch_async`.

Comment: yes i know, but when the url is not reachable, my code blocks for 60secs. any other solution to capture the blocking

Comment: You should be checking the URL for reachability before you call anyway. It's one of Apple's requirements.  If reachability is false then don't make the call.

Comment: Use this code: https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability.  It will allow you to test if a connection is viable.